# System.Xml.XmlException: The '=' character, hexadecimal value 0x3D, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

When I am trying to load the XDocument from the stringReader i get this error:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The '=' character, hexadecimal value 0x3D, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 496.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(TextReader textReader, LoadOptions options)
   at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Below is the piece of code using which i'm trying to Load:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             String body = "<ContactBundleMaintainRequestMessage_sync><BasicMessageHeader><ID>b4cf2093e85242259f0b1b9122b75210</ID></BasicMessageHeader><Contact><UUID>4211feec-464c-4bd8-9490-f1041ed95504</UUID><LifeCycleStatusCode>2</LifeCycleStatusCode><GivenName>Carlo</GivenName><MiddleName /><FamilyName>DiBrigida</FamilyName><Relationship><RelationshipBusinessPartnerUUID>00163e11-a664-1ee8-85c3-74c6366e0886</RelationshipBusinessPartnerUUID><RoleCode>BUR027-2</RoleCode></Relationship><GroupwareSubscriptionactionCode="04"><EmployeeUUID>00163e11-a664-1ee8-85c3-74c6366e0886</EmployeeUUID></GroupwareSubscription></Contact></ContactBundleMaintainRequestMessage_sync>";
             StringReader read = new StringReader(body);
             XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(read);

        }
    }
```

Could you please help me on resolving this. I googled a lot, but didn't get any solution or explanation where exactly its going wrong

Comment: `<GroupwareSubscriptionactionCode=>` isn't XML. So you have a string that somewhat resembles XML but isn't. You can't expect XML tools to work with it. Since we don't know what was intended there, what help do you expect us to provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes must be separated from the tag name by a space:  `<GroupwareSubscriptionactionCode="04">` should be `<GroupwareSubscription actionCode="04">`.

Comment: don't answer typo questions, these must be closed.

Comment: The Xml which i had posted was wrong. I have upated now. Please check it

Comment: Now you are missing a space between the tag name and the attribute. I edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: @MKloster What space?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno This is not a typo question. Please read it properly and reply.

Comment: A white space (press spacebar...)

Comment: A missing spacebar between `<nodeName[missingSpace]attributeName="attributeValue">` looks terribly like a typo IMHO.

Comment: @coders - SO is not a place where basic typos should be addressed. If you've got a basic understanding of XML, you should understand that *neither* `<GroupwareSubscriptionactionCode=>` nor `<GroupwareSubscriptionactionCode="04">` are valid XML. If you cannot identify the errors here, you need to go and familiarise yourself with the basics of XML, elements and attributes, etc, and we're not a place to provide that grounding material either.